# How to modify JSON key name within an array in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, dom-events, node-modules

I have a function within NodeJS which is returning an array of JSON elements

```
let rows = function1();
```

Here `rows` look like:

```
"rows": [
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name1",
    "Status": "PASS",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name2",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    }
]
```

Here, `rows` can have any number of Json elements:

```
"rows": [
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name1",
    "Status": "PASS",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name2",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name3",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
 ...
]
```

In all JSON elements `Hostname` will remain name,

I want to modify the `rows array` such that it looks as below:

```
"rows": [
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name1Status": "PASS",
    "name1Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name2Status": "FAIL",
    "name2Heading": "Not Applicable"
    "name3Status": "FAIL",
    "name3Heading": "Not Applicable"
     ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand correctly, then you need to achieve this result. 
Use reduce for this, very convenient for working with arrays

```js
const rows = [
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name1",
    "Status": "PASS",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "name": "name2",
    "Status": "FAIL",
    "Heading": "Not Applicable"
    }
]
const res = rows.reduce((acc, rec) => {
 let result = { ...acc, [`Hostname`]: rec.Hostname,  [`${rec.name}Status`]: rec.Status, [`${rec.name}Heading`]: rec.Heading  }
 return result
}, [])
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Here, the output is not showing `"Hostname": "abc123"`. Instead it is showing  `"abc123": "abc123"`

Comment: Yes, sry. try now